# Some url of my website get random 403 after changing pattern format

Tags: symfony, nginx

I had just change all my urls in my website. I added language in the url
and sometimes i have 403 in some url.
example of url:
old :

```
www.mywebsite.com/toto
```

new :

```
www.mywebsite.com/fr/toto
```

The problem is that theses errors are randomly and i have nothing in logs
any help will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Are you adding your `{_locale}` parameter to your routes?

Comment: of course, it's very strange because it's random

Comment: Can you show us some logs after this error occurs?

Comment: Is your site live?  Could people be hitting your site using old url's saved by their browser?

Comment: @Gaska : i don't have anything in logs

Comment: @Cerad : i have a listener that force redirect

Comment: you really need to provide ***way*** more information. I mean, I can only speak for myself here, but I'm not some kind of mind reader and hence neither do I know how your routes look like nor what changed, so speculating about the reasons is like poking the anthill with a stick. you should probably post the output of `bin/console debug:router` or something, because it probably contains most relevant information.